# ESS mode R: how to do a javareconf?

Tags: r, emacs, ess

In order to load R with a functional rJava, I need to run `R CMD javareconf` first. This works if I run R from the shell, but I want to run it in ESS. How can I get ESS (that is, `M-x R`) to run with the effects of the javareconf?

System information: 
OpenSUSE 12.2 x 64
Emacs version 24.2.1
R patched: 3.0.1 "Good Sport"

Comment: Why do you need to `javareconf` at each startup of `R`. I just do that when I update all my java core library. Is there any specific reason ?

Comment: It's the only way I can get rJava to load.

Comment: My own opinion is that it will be better to solve this general problem than tweaking ESS lisp files to reconf java at every startup. What is the result of `echo $JAVA_HOME` in your shell ?

Comment: It's valid; I get /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_21/jre

Comment: Not sure because mine point to a jdk and not jre. Normally, JAVA_HOME should point to a jdk. May be tweaking `update-alternatives --config javac` you can solve it. Try to set your JAVA_HOME to a jdk and then `javareconf` once and start R twice to test if it works. Here's my JAVA_HOME : /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk
(I'm using Arch Linux)